# Variable initalization with curly brackets

Tags: c++

Is the following syntax:

```
T t = {};
```

a zero-initalization or a value-initalization that for non-POD types is zero-initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `T object = {arg1, arg2, ...};` is [copy list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). Since you established that `T` is not an aggregate type and that `T` has a default constructor (from the list) then list initialization will perform [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) :

> - If `T` is an aggregate type, aggregate initialization is performed.
> - Otherwise, if the braced-init-list is empty and `T` is a class type with a default constructor, value-initialization is performed.